# typescript Record<K, boolean> with false initial values

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Keys = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'XYZ';

const actionIndex:Record<Keys, boolean> = {}
```

the action index have errors with the typescript asks to give value for `'A' | 'B'`  and so on. how do I prevent the typescript from asking me to initiate the values? or can i initiate the values in some way? or maybe i use wrong type?

Comment: `{}` is not a value of type `{A: boolean, B: boolean, C: boolean, XYZ: boolean}`, as it is missing all four required properties.  TypeScript doesn't affect runtime code, so there's no way to write `{}` and get `{A: false, B: false, C: false, XYZ: false}` at runtime.  If you don't want to manually initialize the props, perhaps you want `Partial<Record<Keys, boolean>>` which is equivalent to `{A?: boolean, B?: boolean, C?: boolean, XYZ?: boolean}`.  Maybe instead of true/false/missing you want just true/missing, in which case `Partial<Record<Keys, true>>` would work.

Comment: hey that's actually works and useful! you can turn this into answer and i will vote up